# What is the probability of $|A-B|<3$?

Tags: probability

Random two points choosen on the $x$-axis $A=(a, 0)$ and $B=(b, 0)$ such that $-2\leq a \leq 0$ and  $0\leq b \leq 3$. What is the probability of 
$|A-B|<3$?

How can I start?

Comment: Well, imagine that Alice comes to the coffeeshop between 10:00 a.m. and noon, and stays for three hours, and Bob comes to the coffeeshop between noon and 3:00 p.m.  What is the probability that they meet at the coffeeshop? ¶ Sorry, couldn't resist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider your sample space: $a\in[-2,0]$ and $b\in[0,3]$. Draw a 2D diagram of your sample space, i.e. a rectangle 2 units by 3 units. Which points in the rectangle satisfy your condition?

> You should have drawn a line from $(-2,1)$ to $(0,3)$. Below that line satisfies the inequality while above doesn't. Then to get the probability some simple area calculations give: $\frac{4}{6} = \frac{2}{3}$.

Comment: why do we draw line from (-2,1) to (0,3) since they are both on x-axis?

Comment: I guess I got it now.  Shouldnt the answer be 2/3?

Comment: Yeh. I did wrong part. Fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

Try sketching your situation: what does the sample space look like, and what does the space where $|A-B|<3$ look like? What does it look like if $A=(-2,0)$? What if $A=(0,0)$? What if $A=(-1,0)$?

Comment: I didnt get it. if A=(-2,0) it should be  $b<1$